# Powershell Script: combine two array in execution command

Tags: powershell

still very inexperienced in Powershell, but as is well known, every journey begins with the first steps.

I define two arrays in the script:

```
$array1 = @("server1", "server2")
$array2 = @("SID1", "SID2")
```

The SID1 and server1 belong together.

I then want to combine the two arrays using a loop:
Example:

```
foreach ($i in $array1) {
Write-Host "Server = ${i}"
}
```

How can I combine the two arrays?
Ideal is:
...

```
Write-Host "Server=${i}" and SID=${?}"
```

...

Can the two arrays be built into the foreach so that both values are filled when executing on the write host?

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Many greetings

Carlos

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$array1 |Join $array2 -Name Name,Id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to generate a range of valid indices for each array:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $array1.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host "Server named '$($array1[$i])' has SID '$($array2[$i])'"
}
```

But a better solution would be to create a single array of *objects* that have both pieces of information stored in named properties:

```
$array = @'
Name,ID
Server1,SID1
Server2,SID2
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now you can use a `foreach` loop without having to worry about the index:

```
foreach($computer in $array){
    Write-Host "Server named '$($computer.Name)' has SID '$($computer.ID)'"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to use [`[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) which provides convenient API(like [python `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function). ie, You could do

```
$array1 = @("server1", "server2")
$array2 = @("SID1", "SID2")


$doSomethingWithPair = {
    param($a, $b)

    Write-Output "I have $a and $b"
}

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Zip(
  $array1, 
  $array2, 
  [Func[Object, Object, Object]]$doSomethingWithPair
)
```

This will print

```
I have server1 and SID1
I have server2 and SID2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) or [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) (if you need the keys to keep their order), might be a good approach for your need.

- Hash Table

```
$hash = @{
    server1 = "SID1"
    server2 = "SID2"
}
```

- Ordered Dictionary

```
$dict = [ordered]@{
    server1 = "SID1"
    server2 = "SID2"
}
```

Then you can [iterate over the key / value pairs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#iterating-over-keys-and-values) either using `.GetEnumerator()`:

```
foreach($pair in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host ("Server={0} and SID={1}" -f $pair.Key, $pair.Value)
}
```

Or by it's `.Keys` property:

```
foreach($key in $hash.PSBase.Keys) {
    Write-Host ("Server={0} and SID={1}" -f $key, $hash[$key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = @("server1", "server2")
$array2 = @("SID1", "SID2")

for($i=0; $i -lt $array1.Count; $i++){
Write-Host $array1[$i] ":"$array2[$i]

}
```